# What is the meaning of "nail" in "if they nail vaccinations"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was watching YouTube and suddenly got an ad advertising the following - the ad is from Bloomberg

> If they nail vaccinations, drugstores will be the heroes of 2021.

Checking the definition of *nail* in the dictionary does not make any sense to me

> fasten with a nail or nails.
> "the strips are simply nailed to the roof"
> INFORMAL
> detect or catch (someone, especially a suspected criminal).

Can someone explain what it means?

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nail) has **Nail 4** *verb informal* Perform (an action or task) perfectly.

Comment: Did you check *all* the definitions of "nail" in that dictionary? Did you check another dictionary? I checked a few of the top results for the "nail definition" Google search, and *every single one* of them contains a definition of "nail" that makes sense here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [meaning of the word "nail" in context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/173323/meaning-of-the-word-nail-in-context)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Nailed it" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94841/what-does-nailed-it-mean)

Comment: it's like saying "hit a bullseye"

Answer (score 61, accepted):

"Nail" here is a colloquial/slang term [meaning to complete or perform something very successfully or near perfectly.](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/nailed-it/) It (probably) derives from the expression "[to hit the nail on the head](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hit-the-nail-on-the-head)"

Comment: Or, colloquially, "Nailed it!".

Comment: You **Nailed** that answer

Comment: @waltinator: Note that "Nailed it!" in particular is often used sarcastically in reference to doing something very *poorly*. See for example the Netflix series by that name.